# Downgrade Google Chrome stable in centos 6/7 using yum

Tags: linux, centos

I need to downgrade `google-chrome-stable` in centos 6/7 using `yum`.

I have tried,

```
yum downgrade google-chrome-stable
```

And also tried

```
yum history undo $id
```

Not much luck.

Comment: Please try to cleanup your post before you request for a migration. We have a strict don't migrate bad posts rule here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you're installing Google Chrome directly from Google's repo via the "google-chrome" repository.

```
# yum repoinfo google-chrome
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Repo-id      : google-chrome
Repo-name    : google-chrome
Repo-status  : enabled
Repo-updated : Wed Feb 21 12:18:18 2018
Repo-pkgs    : 3
Repo-size    : 151 M
Repo-baseurl : http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64/
Repo-expire  : 21,600 second(s) (last: Thu Feb 22 17:02:05 2018)
Repo-filename: ///etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo

repolist: 3
```

Unfortunately, Google doesn't preserve old versions of their browser in their publicly available repository.

```
# yum --disablerepo "*" --enablerepo "google-chrome" list available
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Available Packages
google-chrome-beta.x86_64               65.0.3325.88-1             google-chrome
google-chrome-stable.x86_64             64.0.3282.167-1            google-chrome
google-chrome-unstable.x86_64           66.0.3346.8-1              google-chrome
```

Your best option is to look online for the older versions, from third-party websites.  I did a search, and I found a site that appears to have what you need:

http://orion.lcg.ufrj.br/RPMS/myrpms/google/

I downloaded one of the packages from there, and the key it was signed with matches the key that was used to sign the RPM I downloaded from Google.  Make sure you check it yourself, though.

```
$ rpm -qip Downloads/google-chrome-stable-63.0.3239.132-1.x86_64.rpm  | grep Signature
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Tue 02 Jan 2018 09:24:14 PM CST, Key ID a040830f7fac5991
```